# Is there a way to replace the values of an object_a with the values from another object_b which has the same key as that of the object_a

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have a object say,

```
let menu= {variable: "name", hsn: '630710', operator: 'not one of'}
```

and another object

```
let menu1={hsn: '630344', operator: 'not in'}
```

my aim is to replace the values in menu object with the values from menu1 by seeking the same key between both. Is there a way to get this done. the length of menu1<=menu.

Comment: It's absolutely doable. What have you attempted and where did you get stuck?

Comment: ``let newMenu = { ...menu, ...menu1};``
Does this what you want?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](/q/171251/90527)

Comment: I believe you're looking for `Object.assign(menu, menu1);`.

Comment: @mykaf  i've tried something like  Object.keys(menu) and Object.keys(menu1) and compare the array elements but was unsuccessful.